# How to select this general sibling?

Tags: html, css

I want to select exactly `.ul-two li a` only. But when I style this by this selector `.ul-two li > a` then this also effect `.ul-three a`. How can I do this?

```
<ul class="ul-one">
  <li>List 1
    <a href="#">dropdown 1</a>
    <ul class="ul-two">
      <li>lorem 2
        <a href="#">I want to only select this link</a>
        <ul class="ul-three">
          <li>lorem 2
            <a href="#">dropdown 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem 2 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.ul-two > li > a` instead:

```css
.ul-two > li >a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-one">
  <li>List 1
    <a href="#">dropdown 1</a>
    <ul class="ul-two">
      <li>lorem 2
        <a href="#">I want to only selected this link</a>
        <ul class="ul-three">
          <li>lorem 2
            <a href="#">dropdown 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem 2 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What you were using, `.ul-two li > a`, means select any anchor that is a child of a list item that is a *descendant* (not just the children) of any unordered list. By adding the child selector, `>`, between the unordered list and list item, `.ul-two > li > a`, you restrict descendant to the children only.

Answer (score 1):

The `a` element under `.ui-three` is also under `.ui-two` so you selector fetch every a element as first child of a li element child of `.ui-two`.

Try to use selector as follows :

```
.ui-two > li > a
```